# PHP PDO & MySQL * WHERE OR AND statement issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am currently trying to find out why my login statement works with using a username, but not email (or vice versa if switch in query)

The query only seems to accept the first value of the query, even if I've put it in brackets, it doesn't seem to register the second parameter.

Running the query in phpMyAdmin works flawlessly, but breaks in the script

open to suggestions

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_cms_users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?  AND password = ?";
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
            
            if(!$stmt->execute([$userID, $userID, $password])){
                $stmt = null;
                header("location: index.php?error=failstmt");
                exit();
            }
            
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
                
                $stmt = null;
                header("location: login.php?error=nouser");
                exit();
            }
```

I have tried
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_cms_users WHERE (username = ? OR email = ?)  AND password = ?";`

rowCount returns true if I input a username, but false if I input a email. statements match SQL Database.

Dumped Variables

> SQL: [76] SELECT * FROM db_cms_users WHERE username = ? OR email = ? AND password = ?
>
> Sent SQL: [137] SELECT * FROM db_cms_users WHERE username = 'test@email.com' OR email = 'test@email.com' AND password = 'password'
>
> Params: 3
>
> - Key: Position #0: paramno=0 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2
> - Key: Position #1: paramno=1 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2
> - Key: Position #2: paramno=2 name=[0] "" is_param=1 param_type=2

```
Database output
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [username] => test
            [1] => test
            [password] => $2y$10$QNKXEo3pnGPCjUMnfXlV..JJ4OFcSQJ5EVg75xOjlE7p5pL7Dqwau
            [2] => $2y$10$QNKXEo3pnGPCjUMnfXlV..JJ4OFcSQJ5EVg75xOjlE7p5pL7Dqwau
            [email] => test@email.com
            [3] => test@email.com
            [status] => 1
            [4] => 1
            [is_admin] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [registration] => 2021-11-13 12:21:28
            [6] => 2021-11-13 12:21:28
        )

)
```

File: user.class.php

```
protected function loginUser($userID, $password){
            $sql = "SELECT password FROM db_cms_users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?";
            $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

            if(!$stmt->execute([$userID, $userID])){
                $stmt = null;
                header("location: index.php?error=failstmt");
                exit();
            }
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
                $stmt = null;
                header("location: login.php?error=loginerror");
                exit();
            }
        
            $hashedPwd = $stmt->fetchAll();

            $checkPwd = password_verify($password, $hashedPwd[0]['password']);
            
            if($checkPwd == false){
                $stmt = null;
                header("location: index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                exit();
            }elseif($checkPwd == true){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM db_cms_users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?  AND password = ?";
                $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
                
                if(!$stmt->execute([$userID, $userID, $password])){
                    #$stmt = null;
                    header("location: index.php?error=failstmt");
                    exit();
                }
                
                if($stmt->rowCount() == 0){
                    
                    $stmt = null;
                    header("location: login.php?error=nouser");
                    exit();
                }

                $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
                //make session later 
                //nov 13/21
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row[0]['username'];
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $row[0]['id'];
                
                return true;
                
            }
        }
```

File userContr.class.php

```
public function login($userID, $password){
            $result = $this->loginUser($userID, $password);
            return $result;
        }
```

File test.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    include "includes/autoloader.inc.php";

    $userObj = new UserView();
    $data = $userObj->showUser(1);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($data[0]);
    echo "</pre>";

    $userObj = new UserContr();

    
    if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
        echo "<h1>Welcome back ". $_SESSION['username'] ."!";
        echo "<a href='?a=logout'>Logout</a>";
        
        if(isset($_GET['a'])){
            $a = $_GET['a'];
            if($a == "logout"){
                $userObj->logoutUser();
                
                exit();
            }
        }
        
    }else{
        if(isset($_POST['loginUser'])){
            $userID = $_POST['userid'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

            $result = $userObj->login($userID, $password);
            if($result == true){
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            }else{
                echo "There was a login error";
                exit();
            }
            
        }else{
        echo "<h1>Login</h1>";
        echo "<form method='post' action>
            <input type='text' name='userid' placeholder='Username/Email'>
            <input type='password' name='password' placeholder='password'><br>
            <input type='submit' name='loginUser' value='Login'>
            </form>";
        }
    }
    ob_end_flush();
```

SQL: Dump file

```
-- Table structure for table `db_cms_users`
--

CREATE TABLE `db_cms_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` text NOT NULL,
  `password` text NOT NULL,
  `email` text NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_admin` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `registration` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data for table `db_cms_users`
--

INSERT INTO `db_cms_users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`, `status`, `is_admin`, `registration`) VALUES
(1, 'test', '$2y$10$QNKXEo3pnGPCjUMnfXlV..JJ4OFcSQJ5EVg75xOjlE7p5pL7Dqwau', 'test@email.com', 1, 1, '2021-11-13 20:21:28');
```

Comment: Why you put to execute call two user ids?

Comment: The forms input is  userID, which takes the value as a username or Email. So, no matter what they input the query should find either user, or email. Also, as per the prepared query, it requires 3 values to execute

Comment: looks like you need to use braces around portions of the where clause - more like `where (username = ? AND password=? )  OR ( email = ? and password = ?)`

Comment: I tried that as well, rowCheck still showed a false return when inputting email string.  Ive used ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_cms_users WHERE email = ? OR password = ?  AND password = ?";``` That didnt work, so I did try ```$sql = "SELECT * FROM db_cms_users WHERE (username = ?  AND password = ?) OR (email = ?  AND password = ? )";```  Im almost debatting completely scrapping the username section and just go off email.  Frustrating

Comment: This is tricky for us since we can't see the data table you're trying to query - please share a relevant sample

Comment: @ADyson I added a print_r dump from the database

Comment: from which of your variables does that come? If you can get that out into PHP then surely it's working?? I was actually asking you to show the raw data as it appears in your mysql database directly

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, very sleep deprived, do you want a database dump from the db_cms_users table?  - also, that is a seperate class to display user information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the big update. The context is very useful. It seems like what you're trying to do isn't logical or necessary.

To begin with, everything starts off well. In your `loginUser()` function, you're correctly fetching the user details based on the email / username. Then you're verifying the password the right way using `password_verify()`. That's all fine and sensible.

But the bit you seem to be having trouble with doesn't make a whole lot of sense. It looks like after you've verified the password, you then make *another* query to get the *same* user - except that this time you're trying to put the password into the `WHERE` clause. This makes no sense because

1. You've already found the user with the first query and verified them, and
2. the raw password will never match the one in the database because the one in the database is hashed (as it should be, hence why you used `password_verify()` earlier in the code).

You really don't need that second SELECT query - what are you trying to achieve with it?

If you just change the first query to select more fields, then your problem is solved - you can put those details directly into the Session without needing to run another query:

```
protected function loginUser($userID, $password) {
  $sql = "SELECT username, id, password FROM db_cms_users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?";
  $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);

  if(!$stmt->execute([$userID, $userID])) {
    $stmt = null;
    header("location: index.php?error=failstmt");
    exit();
  }

  if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
    $stmt = null;
    header("location: login.php?error=loginerror");
    exit();
  }
    
  $user = $stmt->fetchAll();
  $checkPwd = password_verify($password, $user[0]['password']);
        
  if($checkPwd == false) {
    header("location: index.php?error=wrongpwd");
    exit();
  }
  elseif($checkPwd == true) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user[0]['username'];
    $_SESSION['uid'] = $user[0]['id'];
    return true;
  }
}
```

---

P.S. Security best practice recommends that when the credentials are not valid you don't let the user know whether it was the username or password (or both) which was the problem. For example if you disclose that the username was wrong, it indicates to a malicious party that they can discard that username and try another one, and equally if you disclose that only the password is incorrect you are indicating that they should keep attempting to crack the password for that username. You should simply state "invalid credentials" in either case, which then does not give any clues about how to narrow the search for a valid login.

Comment: those error handlers are for my own debugging as this is all just a test script,  Eventually the information is going to be valiated through ajax so th user cannot view it.  I will do as you said and then report back. thanks for the response

Comment: `Eventually the information is going to be valiated through ajax so th user cannot view it`...what do you mean? The user can still inspect the response to an AJAX request if they wish to. AJAX or not, you still shouldn't leak that information from the server. So once it's no longer a test script, you should fix it. Glad the rest of it helped you - please remember to mark the answer as accepted (click the tick mark next to the answer so it turns green) - thanks :-)

Comment: done and done, thank you again ADyson. I truly appreciate it.  Trying to change careers in life to be home more for my family. so refreshing my front end skills